How to configure React as a server side email templating tool?
My .NET web application uses an out of date library to render templates into HTML emails. I'm trying to find a new email templating tool that has code completion, type checking, and other niceties.
We are in the process of migrating to React and it occurs to me that React with TypeScript does what I need, except that I can't see how to configure things so that I could, from my ASP.NET web app, render a React component into an HTML string and then send it as an email.
Is there any way to do this?
I am aware of https://reactjs.net/, but this doesn't appear to have been updated in 4 years, and so the support is already out of date.

https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/server/renderToString?

I think that's if you're already in a React project, but I want to invoke it from an entirely different application.

renderToStaticMarkup from the react-dom/server package might be useful for this.

On the server, call renderToStaticMarkup to render your app to HTML [...] This method renders non-interactive HTML that cannot be hydrated. This is useful if you want to use React as a simple static page generator, or if you’re rendering completely static content like emails.

(italics mine)
Calling this function via some sort of JavaScript interop with your existing setup, and passing in the component you wish to render into an HTML string, should accomplish what you are looking for.
